# Return results from stored proc to another stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored proc - [dbo].[DynamicPivotTableInSql1] that I need to call from another stored proc and continue further query creation. I see that the stored proc [dbo].[DynamicPivotTableInSql1] is executing successfully but the results are not getting returned. Could you please let me know if I am doing something wrong here.

I have very recently posted a related question, but on further analysis found that the results not getting returned to the calling stored proc is the issue.

I need to use dynamic sql in [dbo].[DynamicPivotTableInSql1], because the query is quite complicated and I have to extend the where clause based on certain input parameters. I have only posted a part of it.

Thanks for your help and time!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DynamicPivotTableInSql1]

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@str_comp1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@str_comp2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 


SET @str_comp1 = ' comp1 IN (''Capacity'') and '
SET @str_comp2 = ' comp2 IN (''Refinery'') '

SET @colsPivot = 'SELECT STUFF((SELECT  '','' 
                      + quotename(link_id)
                    from [dbo].[test_excel_poc_head] t
WHERE ' + @str_comp1 +  @str_comp2 + '
FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE ).value(''.'', ''NVARCHAR(MAX)'') 
,1,1,'''')'

EXEC(@colsPivot)
END
```

The calling procedure is below:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @colsPivot1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@return_result  AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 

EXEC    @return_result = [dbo].[DynamicPivotTableInSql1]
print('Return Value: ' + @return_result)
END
```

Below is the result of executing stored proc [dbo].[DynamicPivotTableInSql1]:
[image]

But below is the returned result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're attempting to use a stored procedure as a function. A stored procedure returns a numeric value, 0 for success, or another value that represents an error.

Functions do not allow for calling things like `EXEC`, however, you *can* define a stored procedure's variable as `OUT` or `OUTPUT` (depending on the need) and in your case, it appears you only need `OUT`.

Here is an example of how you can do this:

```
/* Create base procedure with an OUT parameter */
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Procedure1 (
    @results xml OUT -- OUT parameter to return the results.
)
AS
BEGIN

    /* Build dynamic SQL statement */
    DECLARE @statement nvarchar(1000) = 'SET @dynamicResults = ( SELECT * FROM Misc FOR XML PATH( '''' ), TYPE );';

    /* Execute the dynamic SQL statement and capture results into the @results OUT parameter */
    EXEC sp_executesql @statement, N'@dynamicResults xml OUT', @dynamicResults = @results OUT;

END
GO

/* Create a procedure that captures the results from the base procedure */
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Procedure2
AS
BEGIN

    /* Declare variable to capture the results from Procedure1 */
    DECLARE @results xml;

    /* Call Procedure1 and capture its results */
    EXEC dbo.Procedure1 @results OUT;

    /* Return the results from Procedure1 */
    SELECT @results AS ResultsFromProcedure1;

END
GO

/* Call Procedure2 */
EXEC dbo.Procedure2;
```

Calling `Procedure2` in this example simply returns the results captured from `Procedure1`. Once you have the results from the first procedure, you can continue working with them.